# How to use IMAP function(s) in PHP to get the mail body content in HTML mode?

Tags: php, email, imap

## **Summary**

I have tried to use `imap_fetchbody` and `imap_body` functions to fetch the email content in HTML mode, but failed. Below is the PHP codes I tried. Could you tell me where the mistakes are? By the way, it's possible that the mail is written in other languages, so notice the charset.

## **Code**

**imap_fetchbody:**

```
<?php
/* connect to server */

$mail_server="mail.example.com";

$mail_link="{{$mail_server}:143/imap/notls}" ;

$mail_user="user@mail.example.com";

$mail_pass="password";

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($mail_link, $mail_user, $mail_pass) or die('Cannot connect: ' . imap_last_error());

/* email number */
$mail_number = 1;       //The number of the mail (The first mail)

/* fetch the email content in HTML mode */
$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$mail_number,1.2);

/* output the email body */
$output= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';

echo $output;

/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);
?>
```

**imap_body:**

```
<?php

/* connect to server */
$mail_server="mail.example.com";

$mail_link="{{$mail_server}:143/imap/notls}" ;

$mail_user="user@mail.example.com";

$mail_pass="password";

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($mail_link, $mail_user, $mail_pass) or die('Cannot connect: ' . imap_last_error());

/* email number */
$mail_number = 1;       //The number of the mail (The first mail)

/* fetch the email content in HTML mode */
$message = imap_qprint(imap_body($inbox,$mail_number));

/* output the email body */
$output= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';

echo $output;

/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);
?>
```

## **Postscript**

Are there any other IMAP functions besides `imap_fetchbody` and `imap_body` that can also fetch the email content in HTML mode?

Comment: Could you define `failed`? Do you get an error? Nothing? Something unexpected? A zombie apocalypse?

Comment: @giorgio Such as `imap_fetchbody`, it didn't show any result on the screen. And `imap_body`, it still showed some “mojibake”(garbled text) on the screen, though I have tried hard to get rid of those “mojibake”.

Comment: Ah, that sounds like character encoding. Base64 perhaps? Or utf8? Can you post the headers of the mail (be sure to get rid of your e-mailaddress if you don't want to get spammed ;))? And a sample of the mojibake? (I like that word actually ;))

Comment: @giorgio
A: http://i.imgur.com/P4T3pkU.jpg
B: http://i.imgur.com/4czDlhs.jpg

A is the original output result of the mail body content. It's clear and didn't see any “mojibake”.
B is the screen shot from my PHP page which I used the PHP function, `imap_body` to fetch the mail content. You can see so many “mojibake” and the headers of the mail above and below the “real” HTML content.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I use to grab emails from gmail and read through them:

```
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');

/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if ($emails)
{
    /* put the newest emails on top */
    rsort($emails);

    /* for every email... */
    foreach ($emails as $email_number)
    {
        $emailMessage = new EmailMessage($inbox, $email_number);
        $emailMessage->fetch();

        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $dom->loadHTML($emailMessage->bodyHTML);
    }
}
```

The EmailMessage class can be found here: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-email-message-class-extracting-attachments/